# Are imported objects non-writable?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I get that imports have immutable bindings.

I *thought* imported objects were non-writable, but then I try the following and it works just fine...

File #1

```
export let creature = { 
    name: 'Oscar'
}
```

File #2

```
import { creature } from './file-1';

console.log(creature.name); // Oscar
creature.name = 'Winnie'; 
console.log(creature.name); // Winnie;
```

**Assumption #1**

If imported objects are non-writable, for the above case I should be able to say

```
creature.foo = 'bar';
```

as there is not yet a property on `creature` called `foo`

but I should **not** be able to say

```
creature.name = 'Winnie';
```

because there is already a `name` property on `creature` and (see assumption #2)
 imported objects are non-writable.

**Assumption #2** (or should I say previous assumption...)

Imported objects are non-writable.

So are imported objects not non-writable?
Or am I not understanding what non-writable means?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Imports are almost like `const`s *. The *binding* is immutable, you cannot assign a *new value* to it, but if the value is *mutable*, you can update it. That includes adding, updating or removing properties in case of objects.

> Or am I not understanding what non-writable means?

*Bindings* can be writable and non-writable (read only). That simply means whether or not a new value can be assigned to it.

When talking about objects, *properties* can be writable or non-writable (read only). For complete objects, it might be better to use the terms *"frozen"*, *"sealed"* and *"non-extensible"*(?), to be consistent with the [`Object.freeze`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze), [`Object.seal`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/seal)  and [`Object.preventExtensions`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/preventExtensions) APIs.

---

*: *"Almost"*, because the module that *exports* those bindings can actually assign new values to them.

Comment: "non-extensible" appears in ES2015 fifteen times (http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-invariants-of-the-essential-internal-methods) so I think you're good on that terminology `:)`

Comment: Phew, lucky me :) Thanks for checking that!